# Internal Server Error with an API POST call using Python script

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to write this code to send an API call to an organization.
however, the jsonRecord I am building shows correct value when using print but It gives me an error when using it via the API requests call.
Here is the code below:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("set nocount on; set rowcount 1; select Right([Code], 5) as courseNumber,  PresentationNumber as presentationNumber, Left ([Date], 4) as fiscalYear, CordinatorEmail as [coordinatorInfo.email], CordinatorFName as [coordinatorInfo.firstName], CordinatorLName as  [coordinatorInfo.lastName],  CordinatorMName as  [coordinatorInfo.middleName], CordinatorTelNumber as [coordinatorInfo.telephone] from bctc.trainingtest.tblClassesALL where (PostCorStatus is NULL and CertType = 'POST') FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER")
 
row  = cursor.fetchone() 
while row:
 jRecord = row[0]
 print (jRecord)

 row = cursor.fetchone()
 
 url = "https://dev.post.ca.gov/CourseRostersWebService/Services/CourseRosters.svc/json/UpdateCoordinatorInfo"

 headers = {"Authorization":"Basic dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
 
 
 y = requests.post(url, json = jRecord , headers = headers , verify=True)

 

 print(y.text)
 print(y.reason)
 print(y.json())
 print(y.status_code)
 print("response headers >>>>", y.headers)
```

Here is the error:

```
{"courseNumber":"30060","presentationNumber":"001","fiscalYear":"2021","coordinatorInfo":{"email":"mawad@test.org","firstName":"Maged","lastName":"Awad","middleName":"K","telephone":"(718)258-9631"}}
{"errorCode":100,"errorDescription":"Unspecified Error Occurred"}
Internal Server Error
{'errorCode': 100, 'errorDescription': 'Unspecified Error Occurred'}
500
response headers >>>> {'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge', 'Date': 'Wed, 08 Sep 2021 16:15:34 GMT', 'Content-Length': '65'}
```

I wanted also to mention when I hard coded the jRecord to a json record, it worked.

not sure if building that object is wrong as it is getting displayed correctly.

Would someone please kindly help?

Comment: Why are you setting ROWCOUNT to 1? What error does the python code return when you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I need to pull one record at the time from the SQL table to process and send the API call.
I fixed the issue by simply adding this line of code:

jRecord2 = json.loads(jRecord)

This will converts the JSON SQL output from string to JSON.

Otherwise it the requests call cannot recognize the object SJON format and it fails before sending calls to the endpoint.

thanks for your help.